# Laravel | custom collection for select2 optgroup and option

Tags: php, laravel

**Using select 2 I want to do something like this (but this syntax is not quite right):**

```
                  @foreach($courseCategories as $courseCategory) 
                     <select>
                         @foreach($courseCategory->courseNames as $courseName)
                        <optgroup label="{{ $courseCategory }}">
                            <option value="{{ $courseName }}">
                                {{ $courseName }}
                            </option>                                                              
                        </optgroup>
                    </select>
                @endforeach
```

**My Model Structure is quite like this:**

[image: Course Model Structure]

In my controller:

```
public function create()
{
    $courses = Course::all();

    
    return View::make('college.create', compact('courses'));


}
```

I need to map `courseCategory` => `optgroup's label` and `respective course name` => `option`

How can I create a custom collection to faciliate this? and How can I use the collection (I'm guessing using foreach) to output values in my view file?

Comment: you want just one select ??

Comment: If this $courseCategory variable is array, how can you use it an string ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a problem in your `foreach` :

```
<select>
    @foreach($courseCategories as $courseCategory) 
        @foreach($courseCategory->courseNames as $courseName)
            <optgroup label="{{ $courseCategory }}">
                <option value="{{ $courseName }}">
                    {{ $courseName }}
                </option>
            </optgroup>
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: Should optgroup be inside of the the first loop?